# How do I escape '&' in a property for use with xmltask?

Tags: xml, ant, xmltask

I've got a property string (loaded from a file) containing the ampersand character in my ANT build-script.

How can I escape that string so I can write it to a xml-file using xmltask?

**EDIT:** The following code works but I can't replace &amp with &amp so I have to use the word 'and':

```
      <propertyregex property="prop"
           input="${prop}"
           regexp="&amp;"
           replace="and"
           override="true"
           global="true" />
```

Comment: &amp; isn't working ?

Comment: It is working. Solution is above.

Comment: Made another edit, replacing &amp; with &amp; doesn't work.

Comment: I use this regexp to match &*; things:  "&([^;\\W]*([^;\\w]|$))"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try either :
`&amp;amp;` which is parsed to `&amp;` which in turn results in `&`
or HTML Entity (decimal) `&#38;`
or HTML Entity (hex) `&#x26;`

Comment: When using &amp;amp; "&amp;" appears in the XML, using the other two results in an error.

Comment: In my Antfile, `&amp;` rendered an ampersand on its own